# Can't overwrite the active admin default redirect path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using active admin in my application. In my controller, I have an action update with `redirect_to` function. But while updating, it threw me an error.

Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render or redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminates execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like `redirect_to(...) and return`.

```
def update
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @user.update
 mailers.notify(@user).deliver     
  redirect_to user_path(@user)
end
```

I tried

1. only redirect_to
2. redirect_to() and return

but nothing works.

```
before_filter :only =>[:create,:update] do
 if self.action_name.to_sym == :create
  @user = User.new(params[:user])
 else
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Comment: I did it and try that not working.  I think The problem is the active admin default redirect path.

Comment: Can you show us your before / after filters ?

Comment: Why you are having `return`? remove it.

Comment: I had removed return even it not working

Comment: You can edit the Active Admin config file: config/initializers/active_admin.rb  and set root to: "admin/dashboard#index"(or your wished path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your purpose? Why you use  `mailers.notify(@user).deliver` inside the `update` action?

1. Move the notification to `after_update` filter in your `User` model, smth like this:

   ```
   after_update :send_notifications

   def send_notifications 
     Mailer.notify(self).deliver
   end
   ```
2. Change the update method to smth like this:

   ```
   def update
     super do |format|
       redirect_to user_path(@user), notice: "Your notice message" and return if resource.valid?
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by adding this to my update action .This works for me fine.

```
 def update
  update!do |format| 
    format.html { redirect_to_user_path(@user)}
  end
```